How do I bake a normal map to a flat texture for use on a model lacking that UV mapping?
I'm making character models for a game I'm working on. Right now, I've got the models set up to simply have shape keys for each of the different expressions. They have geometry, as you can (hopefully) see here. I'm in bed right now, so it's just the basis key, but hopefully you can see that her mouth is modeled. I'm using this head as a template for all character models, to speed things up.

However, what I'd like to do is bake how each of the shapekeys looks as a flat texture with a normal map giving that illusion of depth, so I can just have a featureless face that I can display different textures on. The method of baking textures and normals that I know of, though, only bakes them to a UV map, instead of being able to simply bake them to a flat texture that can be used by a model with a UV map that lacks the original model's UVs entirely.
So, I'm wondering if there's a method for that.
I'm in bed right now, but I'll check back in the morning.

A UV map is flat (2-dimensional), so a texture you bake on those UVs will be a flat texture. But the UV map is needed for baking because Blender needs to know where the data from the model's polygons should be placed on this 2D texture, so that it has some reproducible layout. Of course once you baked the texture, you don't have to use it with the same UV map, you can use another or Generated or Object coordinates, it doesn't matter. But most likely it will not fit the mesh as it did on the orginal. Unless your UV map is just unwrapped Project from View frontal on the face or so...

It isn't, but I see your point. I may have to experiment with it. I've always wondered what exactly Generated means in the TC node. I assume it's just the way the textures and normals were originally generated, instead of how the UV says they should be? So maybe I could bake the normals of one model to one UV, then bake the way they fall on a different model to the UVs of the second one.

No, Generated has nothing to do with normals or textures, they are coordinates that start with (0, 0, 0) at the front bottom left of an object's bounding box and go to (1, 1, 1) at the back top right of the bounding box, no matter what dimensions the object has. It is kind of like normalizing to 1 on each axis and they are 3-dimensional.

Hmm. That makes sense. Looking back, I don't think I could bake the normals of a different shape key and have it look any different than another shapekey. It would still have the same UV map. Project from View might work, but it would end up with a lot of weird overlapping islands, and it wouldn't be as flat as I'd need it to be. Maybe I could try projecting from view on a flat replica of just the lower half of the face? That's an idea, at least.

Okay, so here's the problem. Projecting from view doesn't just unwrap the polygons that are visible. It unwraps all the polygons. So there's some pretty significant overlap on the UV viewport. Any ideas?
